# Maven war project dependant on another Maven war project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, war

I have two Maven projects (inside NetBeans IDE) that produce `war` files. Let us call them Project-A and Project-B.

Project-A is a big web application. It consist of many packages, classes and dependencies.

Project-B is some kind of sub-project of Project-A. It is an application that does a specific task that requires classes from Project-A.

My problem lies in my inability to configure Maven in Project-B to import classes from Project-A along with their dependencies. All my tries ended in either compilation errors or `ClassNotFound` exceptions.

I would want to kindly ask for help how can I configure Maven in Project-B, so I can use the classes from Project-A and the make the resulting WAR contain all the required dependencies.

Thank you for your time,
Adam

Comment: maybe maven overlays can be what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27172264/spring-mvc-maven-modules/27175155#27175155

Answer (score 1):

I assume the classes from Project-A get into WEB-INF\classes. In this case they are meant to be used only from that war.

Extract classes from Project-A in a jar.

Use the jar in both Project-A.war and Project-B.war

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if it's possible, there will be a JAR containing all the business services and classes that project A and B are sharing.
Both projects have this Jar has dependency.
And may be, if it's your need, i will create an EAR not a WAR, with an EAR maven project with project A and B in dependencies.